# Adding an iMac to a Windows workgroup

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have an iMac running Mac OS X 10.7 and I have it hooked up to my Windows workgroup but when I try to connect to it from my Windows computer it asks for a username and password.

I've tried the account name and password on my Mac but it doesn't work and it gives me a dialogue box that says,

> You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

I have all of the file sharing settings set up accordingly so that it should be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

What did you name the iMac? Did you try the username like this:

Computername\jdoe

Where "Computername" would be the name of the iMac.